# getResourceAsStream() method not working for json file

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I a trying to create a .jar file of my JavaFX project in eclipse. I have moved all resources (images and a JSON file) into the res folder and configured it as a source folder. I used
`Image iFloorPlan = new Image(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Floor-Plan.jpg"));`
for my Image, and it works perfectly, but when I try to do `File f = new File(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("Murder-on-the-2nd-Floor-Raw-Data.json"));`
, eclipse underlines it and says 'The constructor File(InputStream) is undefined'

Comment: Well, the error is pretty clear. There is indeed no File constructor taking an InputStream as argument. There is no reason to create a File object. You can read directory from the InputStream returned by getResourceAsStream() (and a resource in a jar is not a file anyway, since it's not on the file system)

Comment: You also forgot the leading slash in the path.